# Custom RateLimit spymemcached Doesnt Increase Value

Tags: java, spring, caching

I am trying to implement a rate limit interceptor. In order to save increment number in cache, I use [spymemcached](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.spy/spymemcached/2.12.3). When I debug, I cannot

RateLimitService.java:

```
@Service
public class RateLimitService{ 

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RateLimitService.class);

    public static int timeToNextQuarter = 15;

    private Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();


    public void updateExpireTimeForCache() {
        int currentMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int mod = currentMinute % 15;
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, currentMinute - mod + 15);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        timeToNextQuarter = (int) ((calendar.getTime().getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
    }

    public long incrementLimit(String userKey) throws Exception {
            MemcachedClient cache = new MemcachedClient(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.3", 8080));
            return cache.incr(userKey, 1, 1, timeToNextQuarter);
    }
}
```

RateLimitInterceptor.java:

```
@Service
public class RateLimitInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RateLimitInterceptor.class);

    @Autowired
    private RateLimitService rateLimitService;

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println(rateLimitService.incrementLimit("GET~" + request.getRemoteAddr()));
        if (request.getMethod() == "POST" && rateLimitService.incrementLimit("POST~" + request.getRemoteAddr()) > 15) {
            response.sendError(429, "Rate limit exceeded, wait for the next quarter minute");
            return false;
        } else if (request.getMethod() == "GET"
                && rateLimitService.incrementLimit("GET~" + request.getRemoteAddr()) > 2) {
            response.sendError(429, "Rate limit exceeded, wait for the next quarter minute");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Application-servlet.xml:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
        <bean class="com.project.interceptor.RateLimitInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

It looks like below function is not okay and I feel like I use wrong class for creating cache object to call `incr()` function.

```
public long incrementLimit(String userKey) throws Exception {
                MemcachedClient cache = new MemcachedClient(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.3", 8080));
                return cache.incr(userKey, 1, 1, timeToNextQuarter);
        }
    }
```

Is there something that I miss or do wrong?